# Slicing pandas dataframe using Django template tag 'slice'?

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-templates

I have a pandas dataframe which I passed into Django HTML. I would like to subset the dataframe when printing it out using Django's template filter 'slice'. Slice works for list and django's object QuerySet but somehow it does not work when used with pandas dataframe. I would like to know WHY and HOW this can or cannot work.

Example: I slice for 1 rows in the example below but when my code run, it displays all 3 rows.

Sample code:

*in views.py:*

```
## Libraries
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

import pandas as pd


def dataframe_view(request):
    ## Creating pandas dataframe
    d = {'alphabet': ['a','b','c'], 'num':[1,2,3]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    return render(request, 'dataframe.html', {'df':df})
```

*in dataframe.html*

```
<html>
<body>
...
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>{{ df.columns.0 }} </td>
      <th>{{ df.columns.1 }} </td>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     {% for index, row in df.iterrows|slice:":1" %}
     <tr>
       <td> {{row.0}} </td>
       <td> {{row.1}} </td>
     </tr>
     {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to slice iterator, but may be you need just use `tolist`

```
 {% for row in df.values.tolist|slice:"1" %}
 <tr>
   <td> {{row.0}} </td>
   <td> {{row.1}} </td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Also, Thanks for helping adding that {% endfor %}.